# Plot X-Y Graph in Java

Tags: java, spring, graph

I'm trying to find some information about plotting with Java - specifically xy plotting. I've come across multiple java libraries that seems old but I'm not sure if we have anything latest in market for plotting X-Y graph in java.

The ones I've come across are: JFreeChart & JOpenChart

Any information in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: Reactive Spring Boot: JavaFX Line Chart, I found this one latest in my bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive Spring Boot: JAVA FX, Reactive Java